# How to get just newest data?

Tags: sqlite

I have a console app on my server. I'd like to download the SQLite database everyday but just the newest data. What's the easiest way to do that?

Comment: Is a "sqlite diff" tool what you need ? use `.dump` to export to text, then `diff` with previous version

Comment: @sfk: I still need to insert it back. Also they use foreign keys.